# Format decimal types without string return

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a decimal value to format, and it works correctly if i use at this way:

```
> string s = "30260649.49"; 
> string result = decimal.Parse(s).ToString("N");
```

It returns "30.260.649,49".

But i need the return in decimal type, something like this:

```
> decimal d = decimal.Parse(s).ToString("N");
```

How can i do it?

Comment: A number has no formatting in C#. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: it is just decimal d = decimal.Parse(s). Why would you try to convert back to a string?

Comment: I have to display the decimal number formatted, but i can't change the decimal type to string. If i do decimal.Parse(s), the return is 3026064949, and i need formatted like "30.260.649,49".

Comment: Number types, date types, etc. _have no formatting_. The only time you see formatting is when you or the debugger converts them to a _string_. I'm not sure what situation you have where you can't convert the number to a string for _display_, but there is no other way of going about it.

Comment: The string you posted shows a string using a US-style decimal separator. What you posted in your comments though is *not* used in the US. I suspect your locale is italian. You should have parsed the string using `decimal.Parse(s,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. You could also use `new CultureInfo("en-US")`. The `InvariantCulture` uses US-style number and date separators so it's a convenient shortcut.

Comment: @Panagiotis OP states that `decimal.Parse(s)` returns a value, so it seems that _parsing_ isn't the problem. I believe it's display that's the issue.

Comment: To format a string using a specific culture you also use CultureInfo. Eg, `myNumber.ToString("N2",new CultureInfo("it-IT"))`. If you don't specify a culture, the web application's culture is used.

Comment: @John on the contrary, check the actual values `30260649.49`, `"30.260.649,49"`. Notice the difference in separators. In a comment the OP says the decimal is ` 3026064949`. That's what would happen if you tried to parse a US-style string with European settings (actually non-US in general)

Comment: Unfortunately, once again someone put the question on hold nullifying the answers :( Your problem seems to be with the culture and separators.

Comment: @Panagiotis OP states that it's displayed as 3026064949 but they need it _formatted_ with `.` and `,`. Needless to say, I think you've addressed both angles anyway :-)

Comment: A decimal itself is a binary value and has no formatting. The formatting is only for the display.

 string s = "30260649.49";
    decimal result = decimal.Parse(s);

Would always return the decimal as 30260649.49.  By default dot is the decimal separator using comma would return that as 3026064949.

Then you need to apply IFormatProvider. ie: A French formatting would use comma as decimal separator:

 string s = "30260649,49"; // if put from test use comma instead
    decimal result = decimal.Parse(s,new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
    //Console.WriteLine(result);

Comment: Whoever that is. I see it as a disrespectfulness to those who write and try to post an answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, interesting, reading comments, looks like you too understood his problem. He wasn't given a chance to update his question. I don't think SO should be a place where people need to chase for previously given answers. Everybody knows how to use google and in practice almost all questions already have answers somewhere.

Comment: @CetinBasoz [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't understand what you mean. I edited it to clarify and it is still closed. In fact people (including you) understand OP's problem but prefer to go strictly against a newcomer. Tell me that you didn't understand or he should instead chase the answer on the internet (then SO should be closed to questions as all new question have answers exactly or similar).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't chase for answers, I simply answer what I know. Anyway, we would agree to disagree. I don't like SO's such policies, you do.

Comment: Analyzing all the answers, i changed the culture for my locale and I really have to convert to string to display as I want. Thanks all the answers and I'm sorry if I could not explain clearly. But i solved, tks all.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is already in the question.

To get the decimal, do not convert it back to a string using `ToString`:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s);
```

`decimal` has no format, it's just a binary value like `int`

Comment: The question asks: `"Format decimal types without string return"`, the answer is _a decimal has no format_

Comment: @maccettura so the fix is simply to not call `ToString()`. This isn't a bad answer. It only needs a tiny fix

Comment: @maccettura, so this is the answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that isnt the answer though.  OP seems to be under the impression that `decimal` has a format and they are trying to get the format they set to _persist in the decimal_.  This answer does not address that at all

Comment: That's the tiny fix that's needed. Certainly not important enough to downvote.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the "tiny fix" is sort of the only piece needed to explain to the OP their issue.  I would say it is _the most important_ part of any potential answers here

Comment: @maccettura it is not the fix. Problem itself is with formatting of the string input (so there is a formatting problem indeed).